# Asp.net Mvc, How to store email values into array and send email to those emails reserved in array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendmail

I want to return all email addresses who are admins and then send them email. Right now I can only send to one email address and I have to hardcode it (I mean I have to right it hardcoded). But I want to send to multiple emails based on my array of emails

```
// Here is my first problem, to save them in array
        public string UserEmails()
        {

            var emails =  context.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdmin == true).Select(e => e.Email).ToArray();
            // First question,  How to save those emails into an array and return those email array then to use it in my SendEmailToUser(); 

        }
```

And here is my SendEmailToUser()

```
public JsonResult SendEmailToUser()
        {
            bool result = false;
            // My second question, Here I want to put those email array, But I don't know how to do
            // If I hardcoded with one email .. let say test@gmail.com, works fine
            // But instead to send to one email address , I want to send to thos emails which are in my array
            result = SendEmail("emails from array", "Here is my subject", "<p>Here is my message</p>");

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And here is my SendEmail (works fine with one hardcoded email address)

```
public bool SendEmail(string toEmail, string subject, string emailBody)
        {
            try
            {
                string senderEmail = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"].ToString();
                string senderPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"].ToString();

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Timeout = 100000;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderEmail, senderPassword);

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(senderEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody);
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                client.Send(mailMessage);


                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the array and call the method for each email.

Use `foreach` method

```
var emails =  context.Users
                     .Where(u => u.IsAdmin)
                     .Select(e => e.Email).ToArray();

foreach(var email in emails)
{
   SendEmail(email , "subject","email body");
}
```

Assuming the `Email` property is string type which stores the email address.

If you want to the method which returns this emails array, simply change the return type of the method to a string array.

```
public string[] UserEmails()
{
    return context.Users
                  .Where(u => u.IsAdmin == true)
                  .Select(e => e.Email)
                  .ToArray();           
}
```

And in your other method, you call this method.

```
var emails =  UserEmails();

foreach(var email in emails)
{
   SendEmail(email , "subject","email body");
}
```

Keep in mind that this calls the SendEmail method multiple times, once for each item in the emails array. The [`MailMessage.To` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to(v=vs.110).aspx) will allow you to send one email to multiple people ( many people in the "To" address) if that is what you are after.